# Tag synonym: Zend-framework, zend-server, zend-server-ce and zend

Tags: discussion

Not sure but these might need merging or synonym  [zend](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/zend),[zend-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/zend-server),[zend-server-ce](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/zend-server-ce) to this[zend-framework](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework).

Comment: Why the -? Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Anything with [zend-framework](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) is either incorrectly tagged or is on the wrong site. The tag should be eliminated. The rest should be synonymed (is that even a real word?), with my preference being to [zend-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/zend-server).

Comment: Zend-framework had the most tag hits I think.

Comment: Zend Framework is what a programmer uses. Zend Server is what an admin works with, which is why I said what I said about `zend-framework`.

Comment: I haven't scanned the questions, but there is some server setup related to [tag:zend-framework] if you use the lucene search engine and some other functions.  We have many [tag:ruby-on-rails] questions here too which is also a framework, and in some cases requires sysadmin effort for setup/deployment.  So [tag:zend-framework] might be ok, in the narrow case were you are talking about the server setup related to using the framework.